# Mapping URL querystring parameters with AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

### Background

I have successfully set up API Gateway to proxy an API as follows:

GET requests sent to `/prod/foo/bar` are sent to HTTP integration at say `/some/api?qs1=value1&qs2=value2`

I've set up qs1 and qs2 as URL Parameters in the Integration Request section like this:

| Name | Mapped from |
| --- | --- |
| qs1 | 'value1' |
| qs2 | 'value2' |

Note the fixed value in quotes - as per the AWS documentation (rather than `method.request.querystring.myparam` for example). In my use case these are fixed values regardless of the request, so tidies up the design of the API I'm creating.

Great so far.

### Problem

But let's say one of the query parameters is long and complicated and I only want to modify part of it. It seems there is no way of doing this without passing the WHOLE parameter through.

For example, let's say I have another parameter `qs3=some,really,long,value,where,only,part,of,it,changes,1234` but I want my API to be like `/prod/foo/bar?q=1234` one would assume I could add another *Mapped from* value like this

| Name | Mapped from |
| --- | --- |
| qs1 | 'value1' |
| qs2 | 'value2' |
| qs3 | 'some,really,long,value,where,only,part,of,it,changes,' + method.request.querystring.q |

...but this does not work. Nor do any variations of it.

It seems I can either have a `'fixed value'` or a `method.request.querystring.entireparam` not a combination of the two.

Is this right, or am I missing something?

### Current ugly workaround

At the moment, I can only get my implementation working like this
`/prod/foo/bar?q=some,really,long,value,where,only,part,of,it,changes,1234` which is long and ugly and seems to defeat the point in API Gatway.

Comment: Hey, @teaforchris! Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Alex no - workaround still in place, even after a lengthy tech support chat with AWS